# How run Softwares as a snapshot?

Tags: linux, snapshot, persistence, sandbox

I want to run the software as non-persistent, which means if any configuration is changed, they revert.

In the Windows, Software Sandboxie has this amazing feature. When the program is started, it starts as a copy and after closing the program it deletes that sandbox and program come to the initial state.

I tried using firejail but I didn't find any functionality like this.

Is there any Linux sandbox or any other software available with this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly snapshot but you can achieve same functionality of reverting program back to original state like windows sandboxie using firejail

Firejail Manual
https://firejail.wordpress.com/features-3/man-firejail/

> --private-home=file,directory
>
> Build a new user home in a temporary filesystem, and  copy  the
>       files  and directories in the list in the new home. **All modifi‐
>       cations are discarded when the sandbox is closed.**
>
> Example:
>     $ firejail --private-home=.mozilla firefox

This option of firejail will start firefox with all the configuration already existed in firefox porfile in .mozilla directory, but it will delete all new changes on close.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find snapshot software but this is a workaround:

I wanted to snapshot Mozilla Firefox and if I changed preference to no cookies and history I would  have lost my logins

So I used git :)

Step 1: Configured and logged in all my accounts in Browser

Step 2: cd to /home/user_name/.mozilla/firefox/profile_name/

Step 3: Made profile directory as git directory using

```
git init
```

Step 4: Added all files to git

```
git add *
```

Step 5: Committed all initial changes using(Snapshot Created)

```
git commit -m "Original"
```

Step 6: Used browser

Step 7: Again in the profile directory,  added all new files in git and deleted changes using

```
git add *
git reset --hard
```

Snapshot is Working :)

Answer (score 0):

Any

- virtual machine (KVM, virtualbox, etc),
- container (LXC, docker, etc),
- jail,
- modern file system (btrfs, zfs, LVM),
- or some apps themselves (firefox --profile)
  can help you with that.

chroot is the option you are looking for in firejail.

use a bash script to automate any workflow of your choosing.

Comment: Virtual Machine Software will create snapshot of Virtual Machines, I want to create snapshots of Software's like Firefox, If I just use separate machines for software then it will be much load for this single functionality

Comment: I think chroot completes somewhat functionality but its all manual creation and deletion

Comment: Ya this looks better, I will look into that... Still looking for automated solution, Thanks Anyway